# React parent component reseting child components state when parent state updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a parent component called `ToDoLists` which contains an input and allows you to input a new to do list name. This component maps over a list array in the component's state to create the different `List` components.

The `List` component allows you to add todo items.
For example: Morning Routine List with breakfast, shower, shave as todo items.

I can get the `ToDoLists` component to create new `List` components. However, when I add todo items in the `List` component state retyping in the input of the parent component seems to erase the state of the child components.

I'm not sure if this is even the right way to attempt to do this. Is this because I need to pass `prevState` when I add a new list?

ToDoLists component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import List from './list.js';

class ToDoLists extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      term: '',
      list: []
    };
  }
  onChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({term: event.target.value});
  }
  onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.setState({
      term: '',
      list: [...this.state.items, this.state.term]
    })
  }

  render() {
    const generateKey = (x) => {
      return `${x}_${new Date().getTime()}`
    };

    return(
      <div>
        <h3>ToDo Lists Component</h3>
          <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <input placeholder='Add A New List' value={this.state.term} onChange={this.onChange}/>
            <button className='btn btn-sm btn-dark'>Submit</button>
          </form>
          <br/><br/>
          {
            this.state.list.map((data) => {return(<List title={data} key={generateKey(data)}/>)})
          }

      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default ToDoLists
```

List component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';

class List extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      term: '',
      items: []
    };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  onChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({term: event.target.value});
  }
  onSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.setState({
      term: '',
      items: [...this.state.items, this.state.term]
    })
  }

  render() {
    const generateKey = (x) => {
      return `${x}_${new Date().getTime()}`
    }

    return(
      <div>
        <h3>{this.props.title}</h3>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <input placeholder='Add New Todo Item' value={this.state.term} onChange={this.onChange}/>
          <button className='btn btn-sm btn-dark'>Submit</button>
        </form>
        <ul>
          {
            this.state.items.map((item) => {return(<li key={generateKey(item)}>{item}</li>)})
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default List
```

Answer (score 0):

The reset is caused by this little part:

```
 key={generateKey(data)}
```

Whenever you rerender the parent, the childs get new keys as `generateKey` is returning a nearly random key. When diffing, React tries to find out wich components were removed and which were addee, and it uses the `key` prop to simplify this. If a key was part of the previous children and the current ones, the element stays where it is, if the key disappeared the component will be destroyed, and if the key is new it will create a new component. So in your case, all `List`s will be destroyed and new ones will be created whenever `ToDoLists.render()` will run. To change that, just make `key` persistent:

```
 const generateKey = (x) => {
  return "" + x;
}
```

(If two lists might have the same name it might be a good idea to take the Lists index as key.)

---

While that works, it is actually hard to store the state now, as it is split up into multiple components. Therefore you might want to "lift state up" so that all lists are managed in the parent, and every change gets propagated up to that parent:

```
  class ToDoLists extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { lists: [] };
   }

   updateList(old, updated) {
    this.setState(({ lists }) => ({ lists: lists.map(l => l === old ? updated : l) }));
   }

   render() { return this.state.lists.map(list => <List list={list} onChange={updated => this.updateList(list, updated)} />); }
}

class List extends React.Component {
  onSubmit() {
    const { onChange, list } = this.props;
    this.setState({ term: "" });
    onChange([...list, this.state.term]);
  }
  //...
}
```